# How do I use an expression with md-colors directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using AngularJS Material and I would like to apply `md-colors=""` values based on an expression the same way an expression can be used with `ng-class=""`.  I have not been able to get this working.

Here's an example :

```
<md-button md-colors="{background:'accent-900-0.43' : mode == 'development'}" ng-click="setMode('development')">
development
</md-button>
```

The desired output is that the md-button will take on the accent-900 background color if the condition `mode=='development'` is true.

Can md-colors be used this way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use ternary operation inside `md-color` to assign styles

```
<md-button md-colors="mode == 'development' ? {background:'accent-900-0.43'} : {background:'whatever_condition_false_color'} " ng-click="setMode('development')">
development
</md-button>
```